# NextJs: Error fetching data at client side component from api on embedded device

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch, embedded

I'm using NextJs to build a captive portal for an embedded device.

The device, when boots up, gets a generic random IP (ex: 10.0.0.1)

Using NextJs app router version, I have a simple Status component, client side:

```
'use client';

const getStatusData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('/api/status',
        {
            method: "GET",
            cache: "no-store"
        }); // No cache

    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch status data. Please try again.')
    }

    return res.json()
}


const Status = async () => {

    const json = await getStatusData();

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{json.data}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Status;
```

At the server side I have the following in the `api/status/route.ts` file:

```
export const GET = async () => {

    let response = {
        data: "TEST"
    };

    console.log("Status API called:")
    console.log(response);

    return NextResponse.json(response);
}
```

Running in the same machine (dev environment) all works fine.
My problem arises when I install it on my device.

Accessing the application from the is like calling http://10.0.0.1 on the browser.

On that situation, fetch fails with the following message:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Failed to parse URL from /api/status
```

And the following error message in the browser console

```
Uncaught Error: Failed to parse URL from /api/status
at updateDehydratedSuspenseComponent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16356:17)
at updateSuspenseComponent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16056:16)
at beginWork$1 (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17369:14)
at beginWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25672:14)
at performUnitOfWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24523:12)
at workLoopSync (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24239:5)
at renderRootSync (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24204:7)
at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23343:74)
at workLoop (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:261:34)
at flushWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:230:14)
at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:537:21)
```

How can I solve that situation? How can I find out what is going on?